# How to rename an index in informix using numbering

Tags: informix

I am currently facing issue of renaming an index to a number.

I have tried the below:

```
RENAME INDEX 584_1973_tmp TO '584_1973';
RENAME INDEX 584_1973_tmp TO ' 584_1973';
RENAME INDEX 584_1973_tmp TO "584_1973";
RENAME INDEX 584_1973_tmp TO " 584_1973";
```

None of the above seems to work. Is it possible to rename an index to a number within Informix?

Comment: Why would you want to use an index number rather than a name?  You could get the double-quoted forms to work if you set `DELIMIDENT=1` in the environment, but I'm not convinced it's a good idea, even though you rarely refer to indexes by name.

Comment: I'm also a bit puzzled — how did you create an index with a name such as `584_1973_tmp` in the first place?  You'd need to be using delimited identifiers when the index was created.  The Informix DBMS automatically creates index names with a leading space when you implicitly create an index (e.g. `CREATE TABLE x(y SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, …)` because it is hard for users to do that.  (See output from `SELECT idxname FROM informix.sysindices WHERE idxname MATCHES ' *'` for example.)

Comment: I don't want to use numbering, I want to use proper naming. The reason for this is because I changed the index constraint from a number to a name, but the developers don't want that so I needed to revert the change and realized that it cannot be renamed back to the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that once you rename an index like the below:

```
RENAME INDEX 584_1973 TO 584_1973_tmp;
```

You cannot revert, you will need to drop and recreate. If it is a unique index constraint, then it will auto recreate with the original numbering after dropped.